# Module Pattern: function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to emulate the module pattern found here:
https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/

Here is my code:

```
var RPSLS_UI = {
settings: {
    playerSelections: $(".card")
},

init: function() {
    this.bindUIActions();
},

bindUIActions: function() {
    this.settings.playerSelections.on("click", function() {
        console.log($(this));
    });
}
};
```

I have included the dependencies in my HTML in this order:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/rpsls-ui-1.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/index.js"></script>`

When I load my HTML, I type in console:

`RPSLS_UI.init();`

Results in:

`undefined`

Then I type in:

`RPSLS_UI.init;`

Results in:

`function () {
        this.bindUIActions();
    }`

What is happening here? Why is the init() function undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function isn't `undefined`. It returns `undefined` because there is no `return` statement. If you want it to return something you could add a return statement to it:

```
init: function() {
    this.bindUIActions();
    return 'Hi!';
}
```

It doesn't seem like it is necessary for it to return anything, as it calls another function that binds a click handler to your DOM. The function has side effects, but doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense! I was really confused because my click event never fires off. I guess that's a separate question now.

Comment: @iparke Are there any errors in your console? My first guess is that you are including that script in the DOM before any elements with the class `card` exist. The expression `$(".card")` needs to run after the elements exist (IE. put the script right before your closing `</body>` tag, or anywhere else as long as it's after all the cards in your DOM). You could always check `RPSLS_UI.settings.playerSelections.length` to see how many elements matched the selector

Comment: 2 for 2. Thank you so much.